# Does ${\sf ZC + Universes + ZFC}^V$ meet Muller's criteria for a founding theory of Mathematics?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy

I was re-thinking Muller's criteria in [Sets, Classes and Categories: page 14](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1372/1/SetClassCat.PDF) for a theory that founds Mathematics. To him, it should be able to be a foundation of Category Theory. He lays down six points that a founding system must posses in order to qualify as such.

I see the following system easier to ponder, since it works with the common mainstream standard set theory line.

Start with $\sf ZC$, define set as an element of a class that is a limit to being element of, this is:

$$set(X) \iff \exists I: X \in I \land \forall Y \in I \, \exists Z \in I \, (Y \in Z)$$

Now add an axiom that a universe of all $sets$ exist, and call that universe $V$. Now, all Muller's criteria would be fulfilled by theory: $$ {\sf ZC + Universe + ZFC}^V$$

Where ${\sf ZFC}^V$ is $\sf ZFC$ axioms with all quantifiers relativized to $V$.

I don't personally see completeness by subset-hood (an axiom of [Muller's $\sf ARC$ (page 17)](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1372/1/SetClassCat.PDF)) to be necessary condition to fulfill these six criteria, it is only necessay in Ackermannian setting to enact powersets, but here there is no need for it for that sake.

This theory doesn't suffer from the main two objections raised in that article, since it doesn't prove the existence of inaccessible sets, and so no Superabundancy; and the predicate $set$ is actually definable here, so there are no objects to be called sets that do not fulfill that predicate, so there is no Insufficiency, and moreover the concept of set is sharply demarcated from non-set classes by definition actually.

What I'm still not sure of is point (D) Categoristan. Hence my question:

> Would this be enough to found Category theory in the way tackled in that article?

Comment: So we have all of ZFC inside of $V$, and for ‘classes’ that aren’t sets we still have all of ZC to manipulate them? What is the additional set predicate doing that just specifying $V$ as a ‘class of sets’ and then requiring that $V\models ZFC$ wouldn’t do? Is there a reason we want ‘sets’ to be members of members? (your axiom seems to be saying that sets are classes which are members of classes such that all their members are already members of other members — what does this gain for us that just modeling all of ZFC wouldn’t give us?)

Comment: @AlecRhea, No sets are something like *deep* classes, for a class X to be a set there must be a class $I$ such that there is an infinite membership chain raised above X such that $I$ has all members of that chain among its elements, that is $I$ is at infinite rank difference above $X$. While non-set classes cannot have that so there is not limit class over membership chains raised above them, we can say that the rank difference between any two non-set classes is finite. And this is what Muller wants.

Comment: @AlecRhea, How we model ZFC? If you suggest to add to ZC the axiom that there exists a model of ZFC, then you'll increase the consistency strength of this theory, that is besides you'll be subject to the objection of *insufficiency* of Muller's and also the non-sharp discimination between sets and classes which he seems to demand. I think the system I suggested is equi-consistent with ZFC, I suppose, and that's an advantage.

Comment: What does $ZFC^V$ mean? If it means that all axioms of ZFC relativized to V hold then V is a model of ZFC. (note that we basically said the same thing btw; if all members are already members of other members, then those members are also already members of *other* members, so on and so forth, so our descriptions of the axiom amount to the same thing)

Comment: Take the axiom of pairing $$\phi=\forall x\forall y\exists z\forall a(a\in z\iff a=x\vee a=y).$$ I usually define its relativization to $V$ as $$\phi^V=\forall x\in V\forall y\in V\exists z\in V\forall a\in V(a\in z\iff a=x\vee a=y).$$ What does it mean in your notation?

Comment: Yes this is the same bounding correct. But I thought you were suggesting the SINGLE axiom of existence of a model of ZFC, I don't think this theory prove that, not sure though? Otherwise if you are suggesting a schema then V would be primitive, but why add a primitive if you can define it?

Comment: If your theory proves that a class $X$ exists such that all the axioms of ZFC hold relativized to $X$, your theory has just proved that $X$ is a model of ZFC and thereby proved the consistency of ZFC. It doesn’t matter what the things in $X$ ‘are’, wether they’re ‘classes with membership chains above them’ or some other thing, if the axioms of ZFC all hold relativized to $X$ then $X$ is a model of ZFC. ($\phi^X$ and $X\models\phi$ only differ in meaning when $X$ has functions/relations that aren’t the ‘standard ones’)

Comment: @AlecRhea, So you are saying that the single sentence $\exists M \, (M \models ZFC)$ is provable in this theory. I'm not so sure of that really. But even if so, if you take the theory $\sf ZC + \exists M \, (M \models ZFC)$ still it is not clear how to distinquish sets from classes, since in such a theory you can have many models of $\sf ZFC$, so how to define *set* in this theory. So your approach would fall a prey to not having a sharp demarcation between sets and classes, which is against Muller's criteria. Unless you add $V$ as a primitive, but why do so, if you can define $V$?

Comment: @AlecRhea, technically speaking $\exists M \, (M \models ZFC)$ is a single sentence in the language of $ZFC$, while $\sf ZFC^M$ is a schema, it is not a sentence in the language of $\sf ZFC$. Of course with the case of $\sf ZFC^V$ we do have $V$ being actually a model of $\sf ZFC$, but does the above theory sees it as such, does it prove the single sentence that $ V \models ZFC$ ? That's what I'm not sure of. For example take a mono-sorted NBG, here you do have a class $V$ and you do have $\sf ZFC^V$, but  $V \models ZFC$ is not a theorem.

Comment: @AlecRhea, see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289401/is-this-class-set-theory-equivalent-to-mk-or-nbg

Comment: @AlecRhea, Regarding the definition of sets you said "(your axiom seems to be saying that sets are classes which are members of classes such that all their members are already members of other members";  I should admit that I misread it, and I'd say yes you are correct but my definition didn't say "other" , so for example any class that is an element of itself would immediately be a set, a nice example is the Quine atom. But anyhow this would be later forbidden by the Regularity axiom of the added theory, so in that theory your definition is equivalent to the one I gave.